# ".replace() is not a function" when trying to use inside ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I'm doing:

```
    function AddSupervisor()
    {
        var employeeID = $('#ID').val();
        var supervisorId = $('#SupervisorId').val();
        var supervisors = '';
        if (supervisorId > 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddSupervisor", "Contact")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { EmployeeID: employeeID, SupervisorID: supervisorId  },
                success: function(data) {
                    supervisors = data;
                    $('#divSupervisorList').text(supervisors.replace(",", "<br />"));
                },
                error: function(data) {

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: supervisors.replace is not a function

If I do this:

```
$('#divSupervisorList').text(data);
```

The the result on screen is this:

```
John Foo, Jane Bar
```

What I want is:

```
John Foo
Jane Bar
```

But I'm having trouble replacing the `,` with a `<br />`. At first I tried:

```
$('#divSupervisorList').text(data.replace(",", "<br />"));
```

And when that didn't work, I went to using a string that is declared before the ajax call. I also tried using `.split()` but got the same error.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**

As many have pointed out, my return data is not a string, but an object:

```
(4) ["Adam Brown", "Karl Walser", "Jeremy Smith", "Nathan Graham"]
0 : "Adam Brown"
1 : "Karl Walser"
2 : "Jeremy Smith"
3 : "Nathan Graham"
```

So, now I gotta figure out how to split this array into a string :-)

Comment: make sure data is a string. If data is an object/array/null/undefined that replace function doesn't exist for any of them.

Comment: `dataType: 'json',`, try using `.toString()` before the replace?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> [dataType is] "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object

So your `data` is actually an `object`. You need to access the relevant string property, e.g. `data.supervisors.replace(...)` - depending on your object model.

I recommend adding a `console.log(data)` call to your success callback and checking the developer console in your browser by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> to investigate the source of your issue.

**Update:** The output of above call to `console.log` hints at `data` being an array. Thus, you need to replace

```
$('#divSupervisorList').text(data.replace(",", "<br />"));
```

with

```
$('#divSupervisorList').html(data.join("<br />"));
```

Comment: change .text to .html and it will be the right answer! I beat you too it, but only  because you helped :-)

Comment: @Casey, wait, what? You were trying to replace the commas that are separating the values of an array? Those commas ***do not exist*** they are a convention for array visualization. In fact, the array is a stack of ordered items, in your case some strings. There are no actual commas there! I thought you were trying to replace the commas inside the names...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I assume OP printed the `data` somewhere where the array got converted to a comma separated string and let OP believe that data is actually a string, not an array. Why so harsh, OP successfully used console.log to debug on her own, that's something I don't see often here, unfortunately.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu -- at first I did `alert(data)` which made it look like `data` was a comma separated string.  So that's why I asked the question I did. Your answer was correct for the question I asked.  But when I took le_m's suggestion and used `console.log(data)`, I was then able to see that `data` was in fact an object and not a string.  Going forward, I'm going to use `console.log(whatever)` instead of `alert(whatever)`.  Much better.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the `data` param is actually an array, not a string, and you're seeing it with commas only because JS is sneakily stringifying it that way. You could combine them in a string using the `join` method for arrays:

```
supervisors.join('<br />')
```

However, if you try to use `"<br />"` in jQuery's `text` function, it will get escaped. You can use the `html` function instead. So,

```
$('#divSupervisorList').html(supervisors.join('<br />'));
```

Comment: *sneakily*...!?  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ . Love the term. `NaN != NaN`. :)

Answer (score 1):

The data you are having in response is a Json and not a string.

```
 function AddSupervisor()
{
    var employeeID = $('#ID').val();
    var supervisorId = $('#SupervisorId').val();
    var supervisors = '';
    if (supervisorId > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddSupervisor", "Contact")',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { EmployeeID: employeeID, SupervisorID: supervisorId  },
            success: function(data) {
                supervisors =JSON.stringify( data);
                $('#divSupervisorList').text(supervisors.replace(",", "<br />"));
            },
            error: function(data) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Read more:.  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify].

Answer (score 0):

To replace commas inside each member of your array, you need to map `.replace()` on the array values:

```
let result = data.map(function(o){return o.replace(',','<br />')});
```

To join the members of the array, separating them with a `<br />`, you need `.join()`:

```
let result = data.join('<br />');
```

Note there are no actual commas separating the array members, that's just a conventional way of displaying array values so humans can read and understand them, but there's nothing to replace. All you need to do is join the members with the separator of your choice (`<br />`) which, by default, is a comma.

So this would also give you the same result:

```
let result = data.join().replace(',','<br />');
```

... because `.join()` would glue the strings using `,` and `.replace()` would replace them with `<br />`s.

Comment: It's kinda weird.  The first time around (when there is no comma) it works fine.  But once there is a comma (more than one value), I get this: `9:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 13`

Comment: Well, it clearly breaks the JSON. I'm guessing your `data` has a `response` or `result` property which actually holds the content you want to run the replacement on. Without seeing it, I can only guess. Replace `(data)` with `(data.result)` or `(data.response)`.